# Reverse filtered array Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, reverse

I have an array like `['a','b','c','d','e','f']` and I want to reverse only a part that I filter previously, for example I filter and I get `['c','d','e']` and I do reverse and the final result that I expected is `['a','b','e','d','c','f']`.

I've tried to do `array.slice().filter(condition).reverse()`, and another solutions from stackoverflow but no one worked for me.

Any idea?

Comment: Lets say the input array is `['a','b','c','d','e','f']`, and your filter condition filters out `['b','d','f']`, what would you like the final output to look like? Do you want the output to be `[a,c,e,f,d,b]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you know the starting index and length of sub-array you want to reverse

```js
const arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

function reverse(arr, i, j){
    while(i <j){
      const temp = arr[i]
      arr[i]=arr[j];
      arr[j]=temp;
      i++;
      j--;
    }
   return arr;
}

const result = reverse(arr, 2, 4) 
console.log(result)  //  ["a", "b", "e", "d", "c", "f"]
```

the code above will  solve your problem in time complexity of O(n)

Comment: This will only work if the thing you want to select is all grouped together. Also, you need to know the start and end indexes for this group.

Answer (score 2):

Just a quick solution to your problem is to get an array of the indexes you've filtered and the replace those indexes with the reversed value. See this example:

```js
const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
const indexHolder = [];

const filterValues = ['c', 'd', 'e']

const filtered = array
  .slice()
  .filter((item, index) => {
    const shouldFilter = filterValues.includes(item);

    if (shouldFilter) {
      indexHolder.push(index);
    }

    return shouldFilter;
  })
  .reverse();

const result = array.map((item, index) => {
  const foundIndex = indexHolder.indexOf(index);
  if (foundIndex >= 0) {
    // found, so we need the reversed
    return filtered[indexHolder.indexOf(index)];
  }

  return item;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Can you predict the output for  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'c', 'f', 'd']; by your function?

Comment: @Sheelpriy `['a', 'b', 'd', 'c', 'e', 'd', 'f', 'c']`, which is logical, even though it might not be wat you want, but the `f` makes it so that that one has to stay in this position and the first character to be moved is a `c`, so that will be the last there.

Comment: So 'e' won't lose its place? I am not sure what are you reversing here.

Comment: @Sheelpriy 5 letters should be moved/filtered: c, d, e, c, d. When you reverse this, you get: d, c, e, d, c. This is what happens when you recess an array with a odd length, the middle one will stay in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is going through the array twice. Once to clear the boxes you need, once to fill them in reverse.

```js
var x = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
var cond = ['b', 'd', 'e'];
var filtered = [];

for (let i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  if (cond.indexOf(x[i]) !== -1) {
    filtered.push(x[i]);
    x[i] = null;
  }
}
var counter = 0;
for (let i = x.length; i >=0; i--) {
  if (x[i] === null) {
    x[i] = filtered[counter];
    counter++;
  }
}

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is basically a mimic of Bas with some different formatting in case you want to use functions. But all credit goes to Bas for doing the leg work for my solution.

```
ngOnInit() {
   const array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
   const filterValues = ['c', 'd', 'e']

   console.log(this.resultFn(array, filterValues));
}

resultFn(array, filterValues) {
  const indexHolder = [];
  const filtered = this.filteredFn(array, filterValues, indexHolder);

  return array.map((item, index) => {
    const foundIndex = indexHolder.indexOf(index);
    if (foundIndex >= 0) {
      // found, so we need the reversed
      return filtered[indexHolder.indexOf(index)];
    }

    return item;
  });
}

filteredFn(array, filterValues, indexHolder) {
  return array
    .slice()
    .filter((item, index) => {
      const shouldFilter = filterValues.includes(item);

      if (shouldFilter) {
        indexHolder.push(index);
      }

      return shouldFilter;
    })
    .reverse();
}
```

Comment: I like the way you thought, but by doing it like this the `indexHolder` is filled by the fact that you give the memory pointer as input when you pass an array to the function. What I would do is return an array within the `filteredFn` function, with `filtered` at index 0 and `indexHolder` at index 1, like seen [here (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/9ztVby0F). Or you could also return an object and destructure with given names if you prefer that.